# Hidden Directories on My Localhost Server (Related to htaccess)

Tags: macos, .htaccess, xampp

I've discovered that some directories on my localhost disappear (or are hidden) when they contain an htaccess file with the following line of code:

`Options +FollowSymLinks`

As soon as I comment that line out, save the file and refresh my browser - the directory reappears. 
I'm running a XAMPP server on my Mac OS 10.6.8 - not sure what other information would be helpful here. I've commented out and uncommented all other lines of code in the file and they don't affect this situation either way.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is the directory a link to a real directory (i.e. ln -s /var/www/realdir ./weirddir ) ?

Comment: @JScoobyCed Yes, that command returns 'File exists'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well a friend of mine helped me figure out this out and I'll post here for future searchers.

The problem was that `AllowOverride` was set to different things in different places - it was set to `All` in `httpd.conf` (correctly) but inside that file `http-userdir.conf` was included and inside THAT file, `AllowOverride` did not include `Options`.

So Apache saw the Options in the htaccess command and hid the entire directory - to punish me for doing something I wasn't allowed to do.

If you are in the same situation - CHECK THE LOGS here:

xamppfiles/logs/error_log

The log said exactly what was happening and why.

Comment: Oh genius! This has been bugging me for ages!

Comment: Thanks! For me I just had to add `Options +FollowSymLinks` at the top of  my htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

This options enable or disable the display of SymLinks, i.e. symbolic links (using the `ln` or similar command).
In a higher level Apache configuration, I think you have SymLinks disabled.
When you comment out this option, you add ( the `+` before the option) re-enables the symlinks for the current folder.
I guess your directory is a link to another directory

Ref [Apache Core module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html)

Comment: Thanks - but I didn't fully understand this answer. I understand (somewhat) what symlinks are. But why would enabling symlinks make the directory disappear or hide? And how do I fix this behavior if Im installing an established server (from a new client) and their setup requires that symlinks be enabled?